# Auto-complete code in IntelliJ Idea 13.0.1 Community Edition not as useful as Eclipse?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way for me to make `IntelliJ` give me better recommendations for coding in Java SE? In Eclipse, if I start typing in '`System.out.print`' it will popup a window with options like `System.out.println`, `System.out.printf`, etc. When I do this in `IntelliJ`, it doesn't do the suggestion popup box as much. The most I can get `IntelliJ` to do is guess simple things like the words: Final, Class, Interface, and so on.

Comment: That sounds pretty broken.  It works fine for me.  Take a look at Editor -> Code Completion in your Intellij preferences.  Are the relevant things enabled?

Comment: Yes, here's a picture of what it's set at now.
http://i.imgur.com/PQTagpr.png
Does it look okay?

Comment: Yup looks fine to me (same as my settings, anyhow).  I'm afraid I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: I just downloaded it and installed it, if that helps any.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of what options you getting, or you not getting any option ?

Comment: When IntelliJ behaves strangely, try invalidating caches (Main Menu | Invalidate caches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a built in compiler, but for IntelliJ you have to specify one.  Without this it won't make suggestions.  Make sure you have a JDK imported with `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `SDK`

If you have JDK configured I would clear the caches with `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart ...`

What you should see is

[image]

BTW There are many templates and if you type `sout` + tab, it will include `System.out.println()`  See `File` -> `Settings` -> `Live Templates` -> `output`

Comment: Yes, live templates for the win :)

Comment: I have invalidated the cache and restarted, but I still have the issue.
Here is what I have on my SDK:
http://i.imgur.com/D8xV093.png

Comment: This partially has fixed the issue, I can type in 'System' and it will give me suggestions, but when I continue to type 'System.out.print' I never see the suggestions popup.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, I didn't type in the right space again and that's why it wasn't giving me suggestions. This answer solved my issue.